# Tmux: showing sessions on bottom row

Tags: tmux

I'd like to see all tmux sessions on the bottom row of the screen, presented the way tmux presents all windows in the current session. Basically a sticky version of the <prefix>s menu.

So the bottom of the screen would include sessions in one row and just above it, the regular row of current session windows.

Any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could put this on your `~/.tmux.conf`

```
set -g status-right-length 80
set -g status-right '#(exec tmux ls| cut -d " " -f 1-3 |tr "\\n" "," )'
```

This will list all sessions, and "wrap" some of the information to make it fill in one line ;)

Now, on your right site of the tmux bar, it will show the tmux sessions and the number of opened windows. The separation will be represented by `;`

Edit: Add the folowing line on your `~/.tmux.conf`, so you can reload the configuration on the fly:

```
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

Now, just hit `<Control + B , r >` and your are good to go.

Comment: This is a partial answer: the question is a status bar with the standard windows listed, and *below that* the list of sessions...

Comment: You can play with `status-right` and `status-left` to show information on THE status bar, but, as far is i know, there is only one status bar.

Comment: This doesn't work if your session name has a space in it, also the format of this is super janky looking as it leaves a trailing comma